# Flash dispatchEvent fired twice

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dispatchevent

I have two frames with as3 code:

```
// frame1:
gotoAndPlay("show controls");

// frame2 - have movieclip with name slide0
// create menu items click listeners
for (var i:int = 0; i < slides.items.length; i++) // slides.items.length = 1
    this["menu_item"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menu_item_click);

// click on the first menu item
this["menu_item0"].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));

// menu item click handler
function menu_item_click(e:MouseEvent):void {
    this["slide0"].gotoAndPlay("show");
}

// in movieclip slide0 on frame with label "show"
trace("slide0 show begin");
```

And I get 2 messages "slide0 show begin". But when I click on menu_item0 I have one message.

Please help - where is a mistake?

Comment: When does slide0 movie clip stops? You make it .gotoAndPlay('show'), so it may go to the end and then again to the frame with the label 'show'.
Also, when does the main timeline stops?

Comment: slide0 have another keyframe with "stop()". So it's can't playing twice... I think :)
But when user click on menu_item0 I have one message...

Answer (score 1):

```
MovieClip(this)["menu_item"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menu_item_click);
MovieClip(this)["menu_item"+i].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

You can try it as well (`slides.items.length`) yeine numbers you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I move dispatchEvent to frame3 and it's working fine.

```
// frame3
this["menu_item0"].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

But the reason for such behavior is not clear...

Comment: Yes, if you join a flex framework forum such as Parsley or Mate then this problem is the most W*F. Seems like it is comes without a reason. :)